# Is there any difference in jQuery("sel1").add("sel2") and jQuery("sel1, sel2")

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, addition

Well, the question is in the title. Is there any difference (performance, caveats) between multiple selector

```
jQuery("selector1, selector2")
```

and adding elements to selection with `add`:

```
jQuery("selector1").add("selector2")
```

Comment: What is "funny" (or at least, i can't explain) is that using `add` seems faster (on Chrome / WinXP): See: http://jsperf.com/compare-direct-selectors-and-add

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the first will create a jQuery object that contains elements matched by both selectors. The second will create an object that has elements matched by the first selector, then create and return a new object with both, *without modifying the first object*.

For example:

```
var jq1 = $('h1, h2'); // Will contain all <h1> and <h2> elements.

jq1.add('h3');
alert(jq1.filter('h3').length); // Will alert 0, because the 
                                // original object was not modified.

jq1 = jq1.add('h3');
alert(jq1.filter('h3').length); // Will alert the number of <h3> elements.
```

Comment: If it is, it's probably negligible in most applications. The biggest difference is semantic.

Comment: Don't forget the wisdom of Knuth: "premature optimization is the root of all evil".